# Number of days (including decimals) between two OffsetDateTime's

Tags: java, java-time

Given two `OffsetDateTime`s we can calculate te number of days with:

`DAYS.between(createdDateTime, finishDateTime)`

This returns an absolute value of days with the difference between: `2020-03-15T10:51:24.608+00:00` and `2020-03-17T09:36:17.001+00:00` being 1.

However I need to get the exact difference including decimals, something like 1.9xxxx or so in this case. How could this be done?

Comment: Get the number of hours and divide it by 24. Or use a smaller time unit depending on what precision you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a equivalent to ChronoUnit.between that returns fraction instead of integer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785747/is-there-a-equivalent-to-chronounit-between-that-returns-fraction-instead-of-int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for an out-of-the-box solution but as Michael pointed out in the comments something like this works perfectly:

```
(ChronoUnit.HOURS.between(createdDateTime, finishedDateTime) / 24.0)
```